# How to get the full url with getDownloadURL() (with token)?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Unhandled Promise rejection: FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'k91a73uzb99' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "No…not get object",↵    "status": "GET_OBJECT"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
  task: AngularFireUploadTask;
  newUrl: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private firesStore: AngularFireStorage,
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  async onSelectFile(event) {
    const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);

    this.ref = this.fireStore.ref(id);
this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]); /*
        .snapshotChanges()
            .subscribe( (value) => {
            }); */

this.uploadPercent = this.task.percentageChanges();
// get notified when the download URL is available
this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.newUrl = this.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(this.newUrl);
      })
).subscribe();
```

}

Expected: 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/< storageBucket >/o/< ref(id) >?alt=media&token=<........>

Actual: 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/< storageBucket >/o/< ref(id) >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says "storage/object-not-found" and "Object 'k91a73uzb99' does not exist".  This means that the file you're uploading with these line of code:

```
this.ref = this.firesStore.ref(id);
this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
```

hasn't completed uploading yet.  Your trying to get its download URL before the upload finishes:

```
this.newUrl = await this.firesStore.ref(id).getDownloadURL();
```

You will want to follow the [example code from the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage) that uses the returned AngularFireUploadTask to wait for the upload to complete before accessing its download URL.  So, it will go something like this:

```
this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
// get notified when the download URL is available
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.newUrl = this.ref.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()
```